# spree translations on heroku

Tags: internationalization, heroku, translation, spree

my problem is that i can't change the language of my spree application on heroku.I changed

config.i18n.default_locale = :'de'

on my local machine it works! But not when i push it to heroku. Has anyone found a solution to this problem?
Thanks

Comment: deleted my answer. posted own Q with more info. Maybe it's relevant to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156765/heroku-i18n-locale-is-different-from-default-locale-works-fine-locally

Answer (score 1):

Have you done the initializer part? (config/initializers/whatever.rb)

```
if Spree::Config.instance
  Spree::Config.set(:allow_locale_switching => false)
  Spree::Config.set(:default_locale => :de)
end
```